# How to remove and change appended list in python?

Tags: python

I have two classes and  I already append some items to the object `ve` but I need to change these items if the `id` matches and remove unmatches objects.

```
  class Env:

       def __init__(self):

          self.ve = []
       def add_new_ve(self, start_position, start_di, vel,id):
           self.ve.append(V(start_position, start_di, vel,id))  
           self.ve.remove(id)

  class V:


    def __init__(self,start_position, start_di, vel,id):
        self.id=id
        self.position = start_position
        self.direction = start_di
        self.velocity = vel
```

but I got this error

```
self.ve.remove(id)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Comment: Please correctly indent your code. It's not clear if the last two lines are part of class `V` or of class `Env`.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I already changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a `V` object to `self.ve.remove()`, not an `id` - notice that `self.ve` is a list of `V` objects, not a list of `id`s. It'll be simpler to create a new list without the object(s) (all objects with the same `id` will be removed):

```
def add_new_ve(self, start_position, start_di, vel, id):
    # remove old objects with the same id
    self.ve = [x for x in self.ve if x.id != id]
    # add new object with that id
    self.ve.append(V(start_position, start_di, vel, id))
```

Another option would be to implement a `find()` method that returns a `V` object given its `id`, and *that* is the object you can pass to `remove()`, provided you also implement `__hash__` and `__eq__` in `V`. As I said, my first solution is simpler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have two different classes `ve` and `V`.

Comment: @i_th My answer is the same, even if it's two classes. Also it's not clear what do you intend to do with the code, you're basically adding one object and removing it in the next line. It makes more sense to first remove and later append it again.

Comment: This is part of my code which I add many objects but after a short time I need to add a new object and check if it is already added, then I need to update it and remove the others.

Comment: That's what my updated code is doing. Give it a try.

Comment: I run it but it is not removed the object.

Comment: Post the complete code you're using to test in a way that exactly demonstrates the problem, so that we can run it and get the incorrect result, and explain which was the result you expected.

Comment: Recommended reading for you: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It works.  I didn't see the difference because I printed the result before removing it and after adding it.

Comment: I also need to change the `start_position` of the others. But I will solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The `list.remove` method looks for items that match, you can either use the approach that @Óscar López supplied or you can make it so V is equal eg

```
class V:
    def __init__(self, start_position, start_di, vel,id):
        self.id=id
        self.position = start_position
        self.direction = start_di
        self.velocity = vel

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.id == other
```

`list.remove` will now remove the *first* item that matches. Although here is the *gotcha* only the first instance that matches will be removed. `list.remove` is lazy and stops at the first matching value.

So in short Óscar's solution is likely better.

Comment: Whenever you override `__eq__`, you should also override `__hash__`.

Comment: You "should" but it isn't required with a list. `__hash__` is only required for Sets and Dicts.

Comment: It's a good practice anyway, for consistency. In case the object gets added to those data structures at a later point.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the argument required for `remove()` is the specific element you want to remove. Here, the argument being passed is the `id` which is not the element of the list. You can also instead code like this:

```
element = V(start_position, start_di, vel,id)
self.ve.append(element)  
self.ve.remove(element)
```

Comment: The iteration is unavoidable, anyway `remove` needs to iterate the list until it finds the object. The above might work in some cases, but to be certain that  it's the same item, you also need to override `__eq__` and `__hash__` in `V`.

Comment: Made changes. Thanks!

Comment: @AchintSharma I just only have the `id` not all information.